# Undefined variable: categories in Blade Laravel 6.4.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

I am trying to show my categories on the site map page with the controller below.

**CategoryController.php**

```php
class CategoriesController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        $categories = Category
                  ::orderBy('name','desc')
                  ->where('parent_id', NULL)
                  ->get();

        return view('admin.category.create', compact('categories'));
    }
}
```

The following is the part of my Blade file where I use the categories variable template.

**create.blade.php**

```php
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Parent Category</label>
    <select name="parent_id" class="form-control">
        @foreach ($main_categories as $category)
            <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

I use every way to get variable and passing but none the didn't work do you have any suggestion?

Comment: you are not trying to use `$categories` in that part of the view

Comment: `$main_categories` should be `$categories`

Answer (score 2):

### You've got two options here.

**Option A:**

You named the collection `categories` in your Controller and pass it to the view as such. To access it in your view, you need to reference it by the same name.

Change this:

```
// Your view is looking for a collection titled `main_categories`, which does not exist
@foreach ($main_categories as $category)
  <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

To this:

```
@foreach ($categories as $c)
  <option value="{{ $c->id }}">{{ $c->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

---

**Option B:**

Pass the data back using `main_categories` as the collection name

Change this:

```
return view('admin.category.create', compact('categories'));
```

To this:

```
return view('admin.category.create', [
    'main_categories' => $categories
]);
```

You can read up more on [passing data to views here.](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#passing-data-to-views)

Answer (score 0):

To be more clear Ill break your code as below and add some details

```
    class CategoriesController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        $categories = Category
                  ::orderBy('name','desc')
                  ->where('parent_id', NULL)
                  ->get();
// Your are passing variable but I change it as below to be more clear

     //   return view('admin.category.create', compact('categories'));
//now you are passing the value to the view
          return view('admin.category.create', ['categories' => $categories]);
    }
}
```

Now lets catch it in the view. Note that now $categories available in the view. If you pass `['A' => $categories]` then view has `$A` variable  so you should **call for the relevant variable that you define in the controller.**

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Parent Category</label>
        <select name="parent_id" class="form-control">
**{{-- In here you should pass $categories --}}**
            @foreach ($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
```